# Excel Interop: Grouping columns

Tags: c++, excel, grouping, com-interop

How do i group columns using Excel interop?

if i record a macro (usually a good way to get started) i get this code:

```
Columns("I:M").Select
Selection.Columns.Group
```

unfortunately this doesn't work due to several problems, at least in C++. First of all, `Application.Selection` returns a normal `Range`, then `Range.Columns` is another `Range`. And `Range.Group` is this method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.group%28v=office.11%29.aspx

This method only works in connection with pivot tables.

So how do i create a column group using Excel interop?

Even if i manage to create a group, how can i shrink/expand it? By that i mean clicking on the + to show the content of the group, or rather the other way around, "click" on the minus to hide the group. If i do that while recording a macro, it is not reflected in the macro at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the fact that the `Range.Group()` documentation appears to relate to pivot tables, if you extract the columns using `Range.Columns`, and then apply the `.Group()` method to that range, it will have the desired effect.  In C#:

```
Range range = sheet.get_Range("c1","e1");
range.Columns.Group();
```

Edit: The complete example, again in C# (apologies, it's the example I have handy):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
app.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet sheet = app.Workbooks[1].Sheets[1];
Range range = sheet.get_Range("c1","e1");
range.Columns.Group();
```

Comment: thanks. what you write is indeed correct. a few hours after my post i found the real problem (and couldn't answer since i need to wait 8 hours). later in the code i call `Range.Subtotal` with the parameter to replace existing subtotals set to true. This parameter doesn't seem to only replace existing subtotals, but also delete any groups which might exist. Even though the `Range.Subtotal` method operates on rows, it deletes any existing column groups if the parameter is set... That's why it looked like the column grouping didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

One thing the macro recorder obscures is the need to use the Range.EntireColumn property.  Here's some code that groups, expands and collapses.  I got this by googling and fooling around, but I think it gets the concepts right.  Hopefully it's easy to translate into C++:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    If .Columns.OutlineLevel > 1 Then
        'clear any existing hidden grouped columns and grouping
        .Outline.ShowLevels columnlevels:=.Columns.OutlineLevel
        .Range("1:1").EntireColumn.Ungroup
    End If
    'group
    .Range("A:C").EntireColumn.Group
    'collapse
    ws.Outline.ShowLevels columnlevels:=1
    'expand
    ws.Outline.ShowLevels columnlevels:=.Columns.OutlineLevel
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the `Sheet.Outline.ShowLevels` solves the problem about expanding/collapsing the groupse for me since i only have one level and i want them all collapsed. thx. about the grouping itself see my comment to Geoff's answer.